# How to stop Pandas DataFrame from converting int to float for no reason?

Tags: python, pandas, types, type-conversion

I am creating a small Pandas DataFrame and adding some data to it which is supposed to be integers. But even though I am trying very hard to explicitly set the dtype to int and only provide int values, it always ends up becoming floats. It is making no sense to me at all and the behaviour doesn't even seem entirely consistent.

Consider the following Python script:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1", "col2"])  # No dtype specified.
print(df.dtypes)  # dtypes are object, since there is no information yet.
df.loc["row1", :] = int(0)  # Add integer data.
print(df.dtypes)  # Both columns have now become int64, as expected.
df.loc["row2", :] = int(0)  # Add more integer data.
print(df.dtypes)  # Both columns are now float64???
print(df)  # Shows as 0.0.

# Let's try again, but be more specific.
del df  
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1", "col2"], dtype=int)  # Explicit set dtype.
print(df.dtypes)  # For some reason both colums are already float64???
df.loc["row1", :] = int(0)
print(df.dtypes)  # Both colums still float64.

# Output:
"""
col1    object
col2    object
dtype: object
col1    int64
col2    int64
dtype: object
col1    float64
col2    float64
dtype: object
      col1  col2
row1   0.0   0.0
row2   0.0   0.0
col1    float64
col2    float64
dtype: object
col1    float64
col2    float64
dtype: object
"""
```

I can fix it by doing `df = df.astype(int)` at the end. There are other ways to fix it as well. But this should not be necessary. I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong that makes the columns become floats in the first place.

What is going on?

Python version 3.7.1
Pandas version 0.23.4

**EDIT:**

I think maybe some people are misunderstanding. There are never any NaN values in this DataFrame. Immediately after its creation it looks like this:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2]
Index: []
```

It is an *empty* Dataframe, df.shape=0, but there is no NaN in it, there's just no rows yet.

I have also discovered something even worse. Even if I do `df = df.astype(int)` after adding data such that it becomes int, *it becomes float again as soon as I add more data*!

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1", "col2"], dtype=int)
df.loc["row1", :] = int(0)
df.loc["row2", :] = int(0)
df = df.astype(int)  # Force it back to int.
print(df.dtypes)  # It is now ints again.
df.loc["row3", :] = int(0)  # Add another integer row.
print(df.dtypes)  # It is now float again???

# Output:
"""
col1    int32
col2    int32
dtype: object
col1    float64
col2    float64
dtype: object
"""
```

The [suggested fix in version 0.24](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) does not seem related to my problem. That feature is about Nullable Integer Data Type. There are no NaN or None values in my data.

Comment: Do you have empty rows in that column?

Comment: If there are nan or empty rows it assume is a float. This is fixed for newer version see [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html)

Comment: @Erfan Yes, I start with an empty DataFrame. But as I show in the first example when I add the first row it is correctly assumed to be int, and then after adding the second row it becomes float, which I find to be super weird. 
EDIT: Wait, no, I never have empty rows. I just have no rows before I add the first one.

Comment: To complicate things more, I'm not even getting the same results as you are when explicitly setting the dytpe.  `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1", "col2"], dtype=int)  # No dtype specified.
print(df.dtypes)` gives dtypes as int, but subsequent operations still result in floats.

Comment: @user32185 So you can't actually set the dtype before data has been added? But what about my first example where I actually add 1 row and the dtype becomes int, but then I add another row and the dtype becomes float? For the record I never have empty rows, just that before I add the first row there just is no rows.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure about the newer version but that problem exist for a while in pandas that if any of your row has NaN, NA, None then the column always will considered as float. So you need to to replace the NaN with some number `df["<col_name>"] = df[<col_names>].fillna(-1)` then use `astype(int)` to convert it to Integer.

Comment: @DataPsycho I think there is a misunderstanding. I know that NaN must be float in Pandas, but there are NOT any NaN values in this DataFrame at any point. I tried what you said, but it did not make any difference, as there was no NaN values to fill.

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to this question. But if you make a dataframe filled say with zeros, and set the frame to int, then modifying the rows won't change to float. It seems only adding rows. .loc is trying to access a non-existent index, so I'm guessing the float comes in creating the new row index.

Comment: @run-out Yes, that is what I observe as well. Maybe you are not supposed to be appending rows to a new indexes in a DataFrame like I am doing. But it is clearly possible to do so, so you would think it would either be handled properly or raise a warning/exception.

Comment: Whenever you add rows to a DataFrame (or concatenate two df's, etc), Pandas recasts all the dtypes. Presumably, it's getting confused about something and defaulting to floats here. Note that if you first start with an empty DataFrame with defined index, and then add values as you describe, you get dtype int64.

Comment: Reading indexing.py  it is clear from the docstrings that .loc is only meant for slicing, not adding rows or columns. It states for class _LocIndexer  the following for _valid_types = ("labels (MUST BE IN THE INDEX) . In capitals no less!  The fact that rows can be made in this way appears to be outside the scope of what is intended for .loc, , so glitches like int to float can and will happen.

Comment: @run-out This seems to be the correct answer. I was indeed using .loc wrong. I am surprised then that except the conversion thing it works fine and does not produce a warning or anything, which the Pandas library does for other things when you use them in a maybe not intended way.

Comment: @PaulMag perhaps it's one of those, we'll just leave that go because most of the time when people are using it to add rows they aren't running into the conversion problem?  e.g. float to float.   That was a great question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`df.loc["rowX"] = int(0)` will work and solves the problem posed in the question.  `df.loc["rowX",:] = int(0)` does not work.  That is a surprise.

`df.loc["rowX"] = int(0)` provides the ability to populate an empty dataframe while preserving the desired dtype. But one can do so for an entire row at a time.

`df.loc["rowX"] = [np.int64(0), np.int64(1)]` works.

`.loc[]` is appropriate for label based assignment per https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html.  Note: the 0.24 doc does not depict .loc[] for inserting new rows.

The doc shows use of `.loc[]` to add rows by assignment in a column sensitive way.  But does so where the `DataFrame` is populated with data.

But it gets weird when slicing on the empty frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys

print(sys.version)
print(pd.__version__)

print("int dtypes preserved")
# append on populated DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0], [1,1]], index=['a', 'b'], columns=["col1", "col2"])
df.loc["c"] = np.int64(0)
# slice existing rows
df.loc["a":"c"] = np.int64(1)
df.loc["a":"c", "col1":"col2":1] = np.int64(2)
print(df.dtypes)

# no selection AND no data, remains np.int64 if defined as such
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1", "col2"], dtype=np.int64)
df.loc[:, "col1":"col2":1] = np.int64(0)
df.loc[:,:] = np.int64(0)
print(df.dtypes)

# and works if no index but data
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0], [1,1]], columns=["col1", "col2"])
df.loc[:,"col1":"col2":1] = np.int64(0)
print(df.dtypes)

# the surprise... label based insertion for the entire row does not convert to float
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1", "col2"], dtype=np.int64)
df.loc["a"] = np.int64(0)
print(df.dtypes)

# a surprise because referring to all columns, as above, does convert to float
print("unexpectedly converted to float dtypes")
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1", "col2"], dtype=np.int64)
df.loc["a", "col1":"col2"] = np.int64(0)
print(df.dtypes)
```

```
3.7.2 (default, Mar 19 2019, 10:33:22) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)]
0.24.2
int dtypes preserved
col1    int64
col2    int64
dtype: object
col1    int64
col2    int64
dtype: object
col1    int64
col2    int64
dtype: object
col1    int64
col2    int64
dtype: object
unexpectedly converted to float dtypes
col1    float64
col2    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: df.loc["rowX"] actually works whilst df.loc["rowX", :] does not. Very surprising. I guess that is the solution to my specific problem, but since it is so obscure I will prefer to do it in a safer way. In your link I do not see .loc[] used for insertion though. Are you sure? I only see it used to change existing rows.

Comment: I ran your code and I do NOT get the same result as you. I have Pandas 0.23 and you have 0.24. So I guess they have fixed some things. Your 2nd and 4th example failed for me.  

"""
3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]  
0.23.4  
int dtypes preserved  
col1    int64  
col2    int64  
dtype: object  
col1    float64  
col2    float64  
dtype: object  
col1    int64  
col2    int64  
dtype: object  
col1    float64  
col2    float64  
dtype: object  
unexpectedly converted to float dtypes  
col1    float64  
col2    float64  
dtype: object
"""

Comment: @PaulMag you are correct, the doc in fact does not depict insertion, only assignment for an existing row.  So we are left with ambiguity there, sorry about that.  Will edit the answer.